# Get ajax function from function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have function like

```
function someFunc(somevar) {
somevar = typeof(somevar) != 'undefined' ? somevar : 1;

$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: 'somevar=' + somevar,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
            // smth
        }   
    }
});
}
```

I want to get $.ajax funciton as object, so I can edit it. Any suggestions are welcomed

Comment: What edits do you want to make to it?

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to do.  You can replace `$.ajax()` or edit your own copy of the JS file.  Once it's loaded, you can't edit the loaded copy.  You could replace it with your own version if you wanted (not sure why though).

Comment: Basically, I'm interesting in any way to extract one function from another as an object or even a string.

Comment: Please describe better than you are doing.  What does "extract one function from another as an object" mean?

Comment: jfriend00: I'm making plugin for OpenCart. It already has function someFunc(). I don't want to edit native file. I just want to make JS script which will get function from native file and redefine "success" option.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply just want to get the result object, just capture the return value. A [jqXHR object is returned.](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR)