# String to jQuery ajax function object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to convert this string to **jQuery** `function/object`?

```
var str = '';
str=str+"$.ajax({ ";
str=str+"url: 'index.php', ";
str=str+"type: 'post', ";
str=str+"data: 'somevar=' + somevar, ";
str=str+"dataType: 'json', ";
str=str+"success: function(json) { ";
str=str+"alert('test'); ";
str=str+"} ";
str=str+"}); ";
```

I want to get the same result as...

```
var myFunction = $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: 'somevar=' + somevar,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) { 
        alert('test');
    }
});
```

Comment: `eval` but this is bad practice

Comment: `Cherniv`, I don't think so. It doen't work - 'not a function'. Can u provide a demo? `Arun P Johny`, I've unparse function... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014735/get-ajax-function-from-function/17014824?noredirect=1#17014824

Comment: look: http://jsfiddle.net/7W4CU/

Comment: @Cherniv, okey... No surprise - you've executed the string. That was not the question. Tnx anyway! 
Do you know how to get jquery object from this string?

Comment: what do you mean by " jquery object from this string" ?

Comment: `var myFunction = eval(str)`

Comment: You will not have a function in `myFunction` but jqXHR object.

Comment: so you need this: `var myAjaxParamObj = {
    url: 'index.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: 'somevar=' + somevar,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) { 
        alert('test');
    }
}` ;

Comment: @Cherniv, nice thought... I can try to unparse string to get params. Just need a tool to unparse it :)

Comment: just cut off this : `$.ajax(` and this : `});` and on the rest string do the `eval`

Comment: @Cherniv, eval() doesn't seems to work again)) http://jsfiddle.net/commanddotcom/KJ7kF/

Comment: i see.. it is more complicated.. you need to use `JSON.parse` , look: http://jsfiddle.net/KJ7kF/2/

Comment: Done... It executes again: `var myFunc = $.ajax(jsonParametersHere);`

Comment: Useful link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003978/how-to-overwrite-the-success-function-via-jquery-ajaxsend-event/12010724#12010724

Answer (score 2):

you can use Function constructor.

```
var your_function = new Function(str);
```

but you have 2 errors in your string, you can't put `//` because you will comment everything after that (you don't have new lines) and you have 1 reduntant closing curly brace.

**EDIT:** to get jquery object, you can execute that function

```
var somevar = 'something';
var str = '';
str=str+"return $.ajax({ ";
str=str+"url: 'index.php', ";
str=str+"type: 'post', ";
str=str+"data: 'somevar=' + somevar, ";
str=str+"dataType: 'json', ";
str=str+"success: function(json) { ";
str=str+"} ";
str=str+"}); ";

var ajax = new Function(str)();
```

Comment: Thx, sorry, it is simple code for demo. Fixed. Anyway, in this case I'll get function, but not jQuery object.

Comment: thx a lot, but i don't need to execute this function. Updated question to be more specific.